# Opal rb eval method throws 'undefined method'

Tags: ruby, opalrb

Doesn't Opal.rb have an eval method?
Using eval both in classes and outside throws `undefined method 'eval'`
Everything else works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Kernel#eval` [is defined in opal-parser](https://github.com/opal/opal/blob/master/stdlib/opal-parser.rb#L7-L10) as it needs to be able to parse Ruby into JS in the browser, so you need to `require "opal-parser"` first.